# Building a docker image on Ubuntu: Error response from daemon: Invalid filter 'reference'

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, ubuntu, dockerfile

I'm trying to build a docker image on Ubuntu and I'm following these steps in the documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html

I'm using a Ubuntu instance from AWS this is why I'm checking the AWS documentation. I am at step three which is:

```
docker images --filter reference=hello-world
```

I get an error that says Error response from daemon: Invalid filter 'reference'. I could see from the previous step (building the image), that no tag has been created to the image. I only receive an image ID/number. I tried adding a tag (repository) using the following command but it didn't work. What should I do?

```
docker tag 8a1b9f676f1a hello-world
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they just want to list images with a specific repository value. There's no need for a filter to do that. Instead you can specify the repository as an arg:

```
docker images hello-world
```